# Using RODE lav mics

Tags: rode, dolby

I have the RODE Pro kit and I've been experimenting. I *think* I can record a stereo interview onto my Android, but I'm not sure how to do it. I've tried Dolby On on the phone and actually recorded on it over the USB-C, but where to go from there?

I'd like to get a lossless recording onto my Mac, but the file is too big for an attachment, and saving it to Drive does not seem to work. I think I set the app to save to the SD card, but now I can't find the file there either, and Dolby has basically NO documentation on this. So where did the file go?

Answer (score 2):

On finding Dolby On's recording files, the [support page](https://dolbyon.dolby.io/hc/en-us) [Where is Dolby On stored](https://dolbyon.dolby.io/hc/en-us/articles/5410331797135-Where-is-Dolby-On-stored-capacity) says its tracks are kept encrypted in app-specific storage until you use the "Share" feature to export them.

The support page [Saving, exporting, and sharing](https://dolbyon.dolby.io/hc/en-us/articles/5410489858191-Saving-exporting-and-sharing) says how to export them, in short: tap the track to select it, then pick **Save Audio** and pick a folder, or pick **More Audio Apps** and export to Google Drive et al. (Also see [Quick Share on a Mac](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-use-nearby-share-macos/).) Pick "Lossless audio" to get a .wav file.

Alas, per [Does Dolby On record in stereo?](https://dolbyon.dolby.io/hc/en-us/articles/5410332454159-Does-Dolby-On-record-in-stereo):

> As of today, Dolby On records in mono. Once the recording has been captured, Dolby On automatically applies stereo widening to the recording along with de-essing, normalization, compression, and fades.

Here are some [notes on stereo widening](https://www.soundbridge.io/widening-techniques). It isn't going to separate out the two interview microphones.